# Date to String conversion - input format of date

Tags: java, date

I want to convert a `java.util.date` object to a String in Java. 
The format is "Sat Mar 22 16:07:12 IST 2014". Can any one suggest me, what should be the Input format to be passed into `SimpleDateFormat()` when its instance is created?

Comment: You get a down-vote from me - no evidence that you've actually tried anything yourself. Read the documentation and at least have a go yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("E MMM MM hh:mm:ss zz yyyy").format(new Date())`. And look [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for other questions like this.

In SimpleDate format there are a number of pattern letters but they all are well-documented. So you should try smth yourself, not ask it on SO.

P.S. I have answered, case you are a new user. But note, questions like yours are hardly condemned on this site.

Answer (score 0):

use "**EEE, MMM d hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy**"
And try to read documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**String newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM MM hh:mm:ss zz yyyy").format(date);**         pass your date which is in Date format as **date**,and **newDate** will return you a date in String Format.